# Is there a way to delete all documents that match a certain field in version 2.4 using nodejs driver?

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently using elastic search for a backend of a cms. My team leader informed me that we'll be using version 2.4 due stability and when I looked at the apis for this version. I noticed that the deleteByQuery Api is not available in the elasticsearch nodejs driver? Is there a way to be able to achieve deletion of all documents matching a certain field from a certain index in this version? The app will be basically a glorified crud app but the lack of mass delete seems to hamper this goal.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there's a plug in that can be installed for versions 2.x for the deleteByQuery api. There is a plug in module from npm which allows the usage of this api.

```
import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";
import deleteByQuery from "elasticsearch-deletebyquery";

const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: "localhost:9200",
  apiVersion: "2.4",
  plugins: [ deleteByQuery ]
});
```

This allows you to call the method `client.deleteByQuery()`